# How do I enable Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am a PHP developer, tasked to write Python scripts.

The script uses `requests`, which I found to be the easiest Python equivalent to PHP cURL.

If you use cURL in PHP, cURL must be enabled on the server, otherwise, the script won't work.

Is there likewise any activation or enabling necessary in Python to use `requests` other than `import requests`?

Comment: Python requests is a module that has to be installed before it can be used.

Comment: No need to enable anything. simply import and use.

Comment: @khelwood. Thanks. On the server I am using, requests seem to be installed. Am I correct if I then assume that it is not standard on all servers running Python?

Comment: `requests` is not part of the standard library. A default installation of Python will not include it.

Answer (score 0):

You must also have pip installed on your computer to install the requests module, pip comes installed with python 3.4 and above so you could do something like "pip install requests"

Answer (score 0):

1. Install requests on machine you are going to use it: `pip install requests`.
   Note if you are on linux you might have 2 versions of python installed: python 2.* and python 3.*
   If this is the case using `pip install <package_name>` will install it for python 2.*, so you should use `pip3 install <package_name>` to install it for python 3.
   (I would also suggest using virtualenv, but this is another topic).
2. If package is installed then you can use it in your scripts by simply importing it: `import requests`

Nothing more is needed to enable/activate libraries(packages). It is the case for all packages in python. (install -> import)

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps in order to use [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

If in Linux, you can `$ pip install request` from the terminal or `$ pip3 install requests` if you are using python3

Then, inside python interpreter,

```py
import requests
url = "https://google.com"
res = requests.get(url)
 
print(res.status_code)
```

This will give you a 200 code

Comment: I tried testing import requests URL = "https://google.com" res = requests.get(URL)  . Exact same script, same server, same directory, two different pages. One page run, the other doesn't. No errors. Any idea why not?

Comment: are you trying to run this from a webserver? what do you mean with two different pages?

Comment: Yes. On a webserver, hosted on cpanel.

Comment: Will you have a look here for more info?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902610/two-identical-python-scripts-only-one-executes